# Prove that $n^{21} \equiv n \pmod {30}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Question in title

If I could prove that $2$, $3$, and $5$ divide $n^{21}-n$, that would be sufficient, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Should I just assume that $n$ is odd/even for each case of $2$, $3$, and $5$ ?

Comment: Since $\varphi(2),\varphi(3),\varphi(5),\varphi(11)$ are divisors of $20=21-1$, $$ n^{21}\equiv n\pmod{330}. $$

Answer (score 2):

By Fermat's Little Theorem,   prime $p$ divides $a^p-a=a(a^{p-1}-1)$ for all integer $a$

$\implies2|a(a^{2-1}-1)$

and $3|a(a^{3-1}-1)$

and $5|a(a^{5-1}-1)$

$\implies$lcm$(2,3,5)|a(a^{\text{lcm}(1,2,4)}-1)=a(a^4-1)$

Now $a^{21}-a=a(a^{20}-1)$ is divisible by $a(a^4-1)$

Comment: Can you explain the first line please? Fermat's Little Theorem says $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. How do you get $a^p-a$ from that?

Comment: @DERPYPENGUIN, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsLittleTheorem.html   and https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Little_Theorem/Corollary_1#Corollary_to_Fermat.27s_Little_Theorem .. As $p$ is prime  either $(a,p)=1$  or $p$ divides $a$

Answer (score 1):

Note that:

$n^{21}-n=$

$n(n^{20}-1)=$

$n(n^{10}+1)(n^{10}-1)=$

$n(n^{10}+1)(n^{5}+1)(n^{5}-1)$

---

For divisibility by $2$:

- $n\equiv0\pmod2\implies2|n$
- $n\equiv1\pmod2\implies2|(n^{5}-1)$

---

For divisibility by $3$:

- $n\equiv0\pmod3\implies3|n$
- $n\equiv1\pmod3\implies3|(n^{5}-1)$
- $n\equiv2\pmod3\implies3|(n^{5}+1)$

---

For divisibility by $5$:

- $n\equiv0\pmod5\implies5|n$
- $n\equiv1\pmod5\implies5|(n^{5}-1)$
- $n\equiv2\pmod5\implies5|(n^{10}+1)$
- $n\equiv3\pmod5\implies5|(n^{10}+1)$
- $n\equiv4\pmod5\implies5|(n^{5}+1)$